# Modify primary key without dropping

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema:

> Table T1 (c1 int (10), c2 int (10), c3 int (10), primary key(c1, c2))
>
> Table T2 (c1 int(10), c2 int (10), foreign key(c1, c2) references
>   T1(c1,  c2));

Now, I want to add a column (c3) to the composite primary key of Table T1.

How can I do without dropping my primary key of Table T1?

Comment: How can I change the physical order, without changing the physical ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the primary key with `ALTER TABLE` without needing to perform a table restructure.

See [Overview of Online DDL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html). Adding a primary key, dropping a primary key, or doing both in one `ALTER TABLE` are all expensive operations.